# Nested do while loop

Tags: c, do-loops

so I've been trying to do a menu with more sub menus. The main menu is a do while loop so if the user tried to enter an irrelevant input, it will let him re-enter. I was wondering if I can do so the same thing with the sub menus but the sub menu loop keeps on going even if I write a valid input. Here is the code:

```
do
{

    printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf(" %d", &choice1);
        switch (choice1)
        {



            case (1) :

             do {
                    printf("4 printfs of choices");


                    printf("Enter your choice: ");
                        scanf(" %d", &choice2);


                switch (choice2)
                        {

                case (1):
                        {
                        stuff
                        }
                    break;

               case (2) :
                       {
                        stuff
                       }
                    break;

              case (3) :
                       {
                        stuff
                       }
                    break;

              case (4) :
                       {
                         exit(0);
                       }

               default :
                       {
                         printf("Sorry that is not a valid choice!\n");
                       }
                       break;
                }
            } while ((choice2 > 0) || (choice2 < 5));
        break;
```

There is still another while ending for the main loop which is not
my concern

Comment: Dear god fix your formatting.

Comment: @CollinD Sorry, I'm on it

Comment: Hope I didn't come off as mean, moreso it was just startling haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `while ((choice2 < 1) || (choice2 > 4));`

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you. But can you explain to me what was wrong please?

Comment: Oh, I just figured it out and I even feel embarrassed for posting this question heh.

Answer (score 2):

> (choice2 > 0) || (choice2 < 5)

Is always true, you probably mean `&&`.

Comment: It won't even repeat the menu if I put &&

Comment: @djechlin This is backwards. The loop should break on that test, not continue. So `!((choice2 > 0) && (choice2 < 5))` would work.